# How to switch between multiple BMP180 sensors?

Tags: arduino-mega

I have six **BMP180** sensors for measuring temperature and pressure. The problem is that I can get the value from one sensor but I need values from all six sensors using a single Arduino Mega board. How can I do that? I have already tried powering each sensor with `digitalWrite` but that didn't work. If you have a solution, can you also provide the code for that?

Comment: what have you tried? ... what problems did you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BMP180 uses the I2C bus and you cannot simply turn off the device, since that can block the I2C bus. Also it has only one, not changeable address. Thus you would need one I2C bus for every BMP180.

So know you have 2 ways to go:

- You could use a Software I2C library and define one I2C port for each BMP. That would use 12 digital pins and you need to find a fitting library, that supports multiple instances. Due to the timed nature of the I2C bus, you most likely will only be able to service one bus at a time.
- You could buy a multiplexer chip for both signal lines. Then you could switch the SCL and SDA lines to each BMP. For that you need the multiplexer chips, 2 pins for I2C and 3 digital pins for input of the multiplexer chips (assumes an 8-channel multiplexer)

Comment: how can i define port ports for each bmp, i checked the I2C library on github but i am a bit confused. Also which library should i use as i am alreading using bmp180 library and i dont think it supports multiple instances.

Comment: I don't know, what you mean by "the I2C library on github". There are surely many I2C libraries on github. You cannot use the `Wire` library, since it is a hardware I2C library, not a software I2C library. I haven't used such a library, so I cannot suggest a good one. I googled "github arduino software i2c" and found [this](https://github.com/felias-fogg/SoftI2CMaster) in the first few results. You need to try yourself and look, which library gives you the needed functionality.

Comment: Maybe you don't find a library, that can have multiple instances, but where you can repeatedly `begin()` the library with different pins, everytime, that you want to communicate with one of the BMPs.

Comment: thanks chris i will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have n-MOSFETs available, a simple multiplex solution would be: SCL directly from master to all slaves. SDA from master to Source of MOSFET (for each slave one MOSFET), Drain of MOSFET with pull-up resistor (e.g. 4.7k) will be the SDA signal. Gate of MOSFET to select slaves (active <-> Gate=high level). Make sure your MOSFET turns on based on your used voltage levels.